# How to send notification from one user to another using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send the notification from one user to another user of the same app.

I am following this article : https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Here it takes username and message. But the username is plain name, how it will identify the which device it needs to send the notifications.

Or it is firebase id: FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
Or I have to manage mapping of user to device on the server.

And what is FIREBASE_URL?

Comment: do you have another user device token?

Comment: yup, I am storing it on server. @Pravin

Comment: You need an API from your server to get the other user token to send.

Comment: username is the receiver username(i.e. receiver firebase token)? @KingfisherPhuoc. Or is it possible to send the only message and at the server, I can add the receiver id.

Comment: so you want to send from android device to device right?

Comment: yes right @Pravin

Comment: ok there are 2 ways 1) from server side 2 ) from device to device

Comment: Device to device can perform if one device is not in foreground( i.e background/killed)? @Pravin Is there any tutorial I can follow to enable device to device?

Comment: @Pravin Sending messages to a device with Firebase Cloud Messaging requires that your code specify the FCM Server Key. As its name implies, this key should only be used on a server (or other trusted environment).. There is no secure way to send messages from device to device through FCM without using a server.

Answer (score 0):

The article you read uses FCM topics to identify users. This is a naïve-but-simple way of addressing users. If your needs are more complex, you will need to manage your own mapping of users to tokens on your server.

For an example of using Cloud Functions to send FCM messages to tokens, see [this sample in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).